# Is there a Map Editor?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In a recent question that I saw in the **Animal Crossing: New Leaf** tag, someone answered, saying that there was a *map editor*.

Is there such thing as a map editor in the game?

If there is, where is it and how do I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no in game map editor. Most likely the person misspoke or was referring to a third-party tool (but I am also unaware of such a thing existing.)

Answer (score 0):

No. I wish there was though. When you get on the game for the first time, it creates the town for you. Unless you start over, you can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no map editor. The only way to alter the design of your town is through a reset.

Comment: I already got the answer, but thanks!